# Interesting "bullet points"

Tags: meaning, character-identification

For some reason WPS Office, when I clicked "bullet point", gave me this character:
[image]

Does anyone know what this character is? When I try handwriting recognition, it can't seem to find it. Same thing when I search by radical. It's like the character doesn't exist.

**EDIT**: This character appears when I copy & paste a list with bullets in it: [image]

**EDIT 2**: I am on Ubuntu Kylin 16.04 if that makes a difference

**EDIT 3**: Apparently there are more... I get these characters when selecting different bullet types: [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Every other function works perfectly fine. There is no issue other than the fact that I can't use bullet points

Comment: The last one looks like Jurchen writing. Are you sure you haven't got any Jurchen fonts installed?

Comment: apparently not in 4-corner (incl.附号) index dictionary, 四角号码查询 27217 belongs to 7 characters including 㐶 异体字: 化

Comment: @droooze Nope, no Jurchen. I used to have a Tangut font installed (like a year ago)

Answer (score 3):

I tested in WPS, added several bullets, saved the file in UTF-8 text, then opened the pure text document in Word, and with the "Atl-X" shortcut I found the Unicode code point for these bullets: F0D8, F06E, F075, F06C, etc ...

They are in the PUA (Private Use Area, E000–F8FF). Characters there are not assigned by Unicode, but deliberately left unassigned. Different companies, organizations can use them in different ways. This then raises a possibility that there can be a conflict with two parties using them in different ways. Here the conflict would probably be your problem.

As what the characters actually are, I found  (201E4) through [zdic](http://www.zdic.net/z/84/js/201E4.htm), as you can easily look it up by radical. And in the Unicode Chart around it, I found another of them, like [(201D5)](http://www.zdic.net/z/84/js/201D5.htm) (This first pic in your post). There are also similar characters to some others of your pictures. The characters found are in CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B.

On zdic, there is absolutely no explanation of the characters. They are ancient character or character variations that are not used today.

BTW: I don't know if you can see the characters in the post. The linked pages in zdic use pictures.

Comment: Good findings and research! We learned!